# Trouble with DictWriter when writing dictionary with list of values

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

So i have a dictionary that was created after I scraped data from websites using selenium.

The format preview of the dictionary is as such. I printed the dictionary and it is working fine.

```
{'Website A': [apple,orange,pear], 'Website B': [apple,watermelon], 'Website C': [orange,pear]}
```

Below is my attempted code for the writing to csv. I understand that `writerow` requires some form of manipulation but how should I configure such that my list is correctly reflected each website? I tried to zip the dictionary values but it doesn't seem to display the data correctly. `website_names` is a list of website names that are the same as the keys in the dictionary.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w',  newline = '') as csvfile:
cols = website_names
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = cols, delimiter =';', extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(final_dict.keys())
writer.writerows(zip(*final_dict.values()))
```

This is how I'd like the data to be written on the csv file.

| Website | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Website A | apple, pear, orange |
| Website B | apple, watermelon |
| Website C | orange, pear |

But this is how it is displaying right now, everything smushed into two rows.

| Website A ; Website B; Website C |  |
| --- | --- |
| [apple,pear,orange];[apple,watermelon];[orange,pear] |  |

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I guess `writer.writerows` writes rows, at its name suggests. So you are indeed writing a row with the keys of your dictionary, and a row with the values. You should probably iterate over `final_dict.items()` (which contains tuples (key, value)), and write a row for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? (refer to [csv doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)):

```
>>> a={'Website A': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'], 'Website B': ['apple', 'watermelon'], 'Website C': ['orange', 'pear']}
>>> cols = ['Website', 'Data']
>>> f=[]
>>> for i in a:
...     f.append({cols[0]: i, cols[1]: a[i]})
... 
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=cols)
...     writer.writeheader()
...     writer.writerows(f)
```